# Python: Why does pip install not deploy my code from sdist?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I am trying to package a small Python 3.9 app in a `.tar.gz` software distribution file (aka "sdist").

My code has this structure:

```
my-code
  PackageA
    PackageB
      Module1.py
      __init__.py 
    __init__.py
  setup.py
```

My `setup.py` file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="my-code",
    version="0.1",
    install_requires=[],
    packages=find_packages(include=["PackageA.PackageB"]),
    include_package_data=True,
    description="My Code"
)
```

When I run `python setup.py sdist --formats=gztar` I successfully get a `my-code-0.1.tar.gz` file and I can see that it contains my `.py` files.

However, when I run `pip install my-code-0.1.tar.gz` it seems that `pip` does not compile and deploy my `.py` files. I.e. when I install into a `venv` and look inside the `Lib/site-packages` directory for the `venv` I only see a directory called `my_code-0.1-py3.9.egg-info` and my code is not in it. Attempts to import or run my module that's in `PackageA.PackageB` fail.

My question is - **Why is my code not built and installed by `pip install` and how can I fix this?**

Comment: I tried replicating your package. It seems the package is importable as `MyPackage`. Perhaps renaming `MyPackage` to `my_code` will help.

Comment: Thanks Tim. You're right. I made a mistake by oversimplifying my example. I will now update my question to include better instruction for reproducing my issue. The main difference from before is that my module is inside a package that is inside another package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR because `find_packages(include=["PackageA.PackageB"])` will filter out the parent `PackageA`, so it is not included in the installation. Just use

```
setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

and it will be fine.

Longer explanation is that the `include` arg does not mean "include in addition to what `find_packages()` finds". It means "include only packages found by `find_packages()` which are in the `include` filter list", so it can only shrink the package selection. Compare the output of

```
$ python -c "from setuptools import find_packages as f; print(f())"
['PackageA', 'PackageA.PackageB']
```

vs

```
$ python -c "from setuptools import find_packages as f; print(f(include=['PackageA.PackageB']))"
['PackageA.PackageB']
```

Since `PackageA` is not included, `PackageA/__init__.py` will be omitted in the source distribution, effectively removing the package property from `PackageA` - in the tar archive, it will be a regular directory now. Running `pip install mydist.tar.gz` won't find `PackageA` anymore, thus `PackageA.PackageB` is not findable as well. Consequently, nothing will be installed. [Automatic package discovery](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#automatic-package-discovery) section in `setuptools` docs contains a short mentioning of the `include` and `exclude` arguments to `find_packages()`, but IMO a lot more helpful is the function's docstring:

```
>>> from setuptools import find_packages
>>> help(find_packages)
find(where='.', exclude=(), include=('*',)) method of builtins.type instance
    Return a list all Python packages found within directory 'where'

    ...

    'include' is a sequence of package names to include.  If it's
    specified, only the named packages will be included.  If it's not
    specified, all found packages will be included.  'include' can contain
    shell style wildcard patterns just like 'exclude'.
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed and educational answer. Much appreciated 